# Ajax does not return any result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My Ajax function does not return any result

```
<div id="container">                
    <div id="connexion">
        <form  method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="login">
            <input type="password" id="password"><br />
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="ok" value="OK" class="btn "><br /><br />
            <span id="errormess"></span>
        </form >
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ok").click(function() {
        var login = $("#login").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var dataString = 'login='+ login + '&password=' + password;
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: 'login.php',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    $('#errormess').html("problem");
                } else { 
                    $('#errormess').html(data);
                }   
            }//success
        });//ajax
        return false;
    });//ok
});//document
```

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE login ='$login' AND password=$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $userId= $row["id"];
        $today=time();
        $week=strftime('%W',$today) ;
    }
    $arr = array(
        'userId' => $userId,
        'week' => $week,   
     );
    echo json_encode($arr);       
}
```

Comment: Change `<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="ok" value="OK" class="btn ">;`   to `<input name="Submit" type="button" id="ok" value="OK" class="btn ">;`

Comment: @Max he isn't listening for submit event nor is preventing it, it will reload the page and js will not execute

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the button click is submitting the form in the standard manner, meaning your AJAX request is prevented from completing. It's better practice to hook to the `submit` event of the `form`.

Also note that your PHP code will never return `0`, it would be better to have a `error` handler should the AJAX not complete as expected. Finally, your current code is wide open to attack; you should look in to using SSL and using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

That said, here's a fix for your AJAX issues:

```
<div id="container">                
    <div id="connexion">
        <form id="myform" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="login">
            <input type="password" id="password"><br />
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="ok" value="OK" class="btn "><br /><br />
            <span id="errormess"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop standard form submission

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: 'login.php',
        data: {
            login: $("#login").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#errormess').html(data); 
        }
        error: function() {
            $('#errormess').html("problem");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving the data parameter wrongly. It should be like

```
var dataString = {"login": login,
                   "password": password}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">                
        <div id="connexion">
            <form  method="post" action="">
               <input type="text" id="login">
               <input type="password" id="password">
               <br />
        <input name="Submit" type="button" id="ok" value="OK" class="btn ">;      
               <br /> <br />
               <span id="errormess"></span>
           </form >
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#ok").click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var login = $("#login").val();
              var password = $("#password").val();
              var dataString = {"login": login,
                   "password": password}
              $.ajax({ 
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'login.php',
                  data: dataString,
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(data) {
                     if (data == 0) {
                            $('#errormess').html("problem");
                     } else { 
                            $('#errormess').html(data);
                     }   
                   }//success
                });//ajax
                return false;
            });//ok
     });//document
```

Also change the input type from `submit` to `button` and have and `e.preventDefault()` in your JS.

Comment: Providing an object to `data` is fine. In fact it's better, as it means the values will be encoded to be URL-safe.

Answer (score 0):

**javascript code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ok").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = (this.form).serialize(); // added code 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'login.php',  
                data: data,   
                dataType:'json',  
                type:'POST',  
                async:false, 
                success: function(data) {       
                    if (data.success == 0) {  // added code 
                        $('#errormess').html("problem");
                    } else { 
                        $('#errormess').html(data);
                    }  
                },
                error: function(data) { // if error occured

                }
            });
        });//ok
    });//document
```

**php code :**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE login ='$login' AND    
 password=$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $userId = $row["id"];
        $today = time();
        $week = strftime('%W', $today);
    }
    $arr = array(
        'userId' => $userId,
        'week' => $week,
    );
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {  // added code 
    $arr = array("success" => '0');
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Please do check. I have modified the response from PHP as well as jquery code.